# session_start() doesn't work online

Tags: php

I'm having a problem to set a session for a user. it's working in my localhost but online it doesn't work.

I have a username called 's' and I have created a page to see what is the problem

here is the code. test.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
require 'connect.php';

$username = @$_POST['username'];

?>

<div class="center_body">
    <div class="search_field">
            <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <td align="left">username:</td>
                    <td align="right"><input type="text" name="username" class="search" /></td>
                </tr>

                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="log in" class="search" /></p>
            </form>
            </tr>

    </div>
</div>

<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysql_error);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $user = $row['username'];

    }

    if($username == $user)
    {
        echo '<div class="search_field"><b>you have logged successfully</b></div></ br>';
       $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
        echo $_SESSION['username'];
    }

?>
```

like above code, it works, and also I can print the username. but when I edit the test.php to be

```
<?php 
session_start();
require 'connect.php';
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
        echo $_SESSION['username'];
    }

?>
```

now, this page should print username because I have successfully created the session. but it prints nothing so session seems not working

what do you thing is the problem?

EDIT: 
connect.php

```
<?php

$connect = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("error in connection");
$select  = @mysql_select_db("abc") or die ("no databse selected");

?>
```

of course I changed data to be connected to my host databas

Comment: Have you tried enabling `error_reporting`? After you got it, please google the error message.

Comment: Every time someone does `$username = @$_POST['username'];` a baby dies.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

        if($username == $row['username'])
        {
            echo '<div class="search_field"><b>you have logged successfully</b></div></ br>';
           $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
           break;

        }

    }    
}
```

Comment: yes it works and also my code works. but when my I delete all queries and refresh the page I can't see my name it's something like the session doesn't work. you may need ti read my post again because I explained there

Comment: if this code didn't solve your problem , somewhere in connect.php you clearing the sessions, also check the session lifetime configuration.

Comment: ok you can see my connect.php in the post. where I can see session lifetime configuration?

Comment: also follow @mario comment. you should see a error or something if session won't work.

Comment: `session_cache_expire()` no result with this function :( . I put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of file but I can't see any error message

Comment: Warning: Unknown: open(/var/php_sessions/sess_af4a992386ddd4f3e5fb02a13c7f5bcf, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/php_sessions) in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score -1):

ok guys as I thought it's from my host site.

the support tell me "I have set session.save_path for your account." and the problem is solved.

big thanks to you guys and especially for Danial :)

all the best to you :)

Comment: welcome, but its better if you remove this answer and update your post  :) this is not answer at all :)